# Can't register Gitlab without e-mail server

Tags: git, configuration, gitlab, mail-server

I just installed [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and I can login as admin. However, when I register as a new user it tells me that I have to click on my confirmation e-mail link first. The problem is that we do not have a mail server set up. Therefore, the e-mail is not being sent.

Is there any way to remove this confirmation feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just login as an administrator (root) and confirm the user manually.

I faced a similar problem and this trick helped me.